# Check if name's already in ListView column

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I have a ListView with 5 columns (`ActivityID` , `Name`, `Date`, `Nstudent`, `NGuide`). I use this method to add items:

```
            // fill the activities listview within the panel with a list of activities
            List<Activity> activitiesList = activity_Service.GetActivities();

            // clear the listview before filling it again
            listViewActivities.Items.Clear();


            foreach (Activity a in activitiesList)
            {
                ListViewItem List = new ListViewItem(a.ActivityID.ToString());
                List.Tag = a;
                List.SubItems.Add(a.Name);
                List.SubItems.Add(a.Date);
                List.SubItems.Add(a.NStudent.ToString());
                List.SubItems.Add(a.NGuide.ToString());


                listViewActivities.Items.Add(List);
                //List view task (right arrow) then View and then details to see the columns
            }
        }

    }
    private void btnAddActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ActivityID = int.Parse(txtbActivityID.Text);
        string Name = txtbActivityName.Text;
        string Date = CBDay.GetItemText(CBDay.SelectedItem);
        activity_Service.Add_Activity(ActivityID, Name, Date);
        listViewActivities.Items.Clear();
        showPanel("Activities");
    }
```

[image: The Listview and add option]

I want to check before I add an Activity if the activity name is already in use.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Check where? You mean in `btnAddActivity_Click`? or in `foreach`?

Comment: In the btnAddActivity_Click

Comment: Mabe: `If listViewActivities.FindItemWithText(txtbActivityName.Text, True, 0) IsNot Nothing Then Return`

Comment: Separating the model from the view is a key programming technique.  GetActivities() should get you 95% there, seems you just forgot to use it in Add_Activity() to reject a duplicate activity.  Don't pass that job to ListView, it doesn't care about duplicates.

Comment: Or maybe: `If listViewActivities.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).Any(Function(x) x.SubItems(1).Text.ToLower = txtbActivityName.Text.ToLower) Then Return` AND please read the previous comment carefully.